# How to convert a string to JSON Array in Swift with SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, swift

I have a json array in string format, however for some reason I cannot convert it to JSON array with SwiftyJSON. It might have something to do with json structure. How do I do it?

Here is the string

```
[{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"1","Value":"1"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"2","Value":"2"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"3","Value":"3"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"4","Value":"4"},{"Disabled":false,"Group":null,"Selected":false,"Text":"5","Value":"5"}]
```

Here is my code:

```
let json = JSON(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for that then you can get `JSON` like as follow.

```
import SwiftyJSON

let json = JSON(data: dataFromNetworking)
let json = JSON(jsonObject)
if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)
}
```

*Edit:* **Swift 3**

```
if let dataFromString = jsonString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)    
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You should cast your data to array like this way:

```
if let arr = (data as? JSON)?.array {
// do something with your array
}
```

Comment: what is 'data' here? our string ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this:

```
let json = JSON(jsonString)
if let array = json?.array {
    // do something with array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this:

```
if let jsonString = json["Data"].string!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding){

            let json = JSON(data: jsonString)
            print(json[0])

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem resolved using this

```
    let objectData = responseString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
 let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(objectData!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
let myjson = JSON(json)
```